# amp-html dynamic title tag

Tags: json, amp-html

I have a url with an id of a JSON object and have to load the object's properties via this id. In the body this is not a problem because I can get the properties via the amp-list tag. However, the object's name should be in the title tag in the head. I don't think I can put an amp-list in the head. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you checked the [amp-list docs](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-list)?
The code snippet sample seems to use title so it might help you.

Comment: I meant the title tag in the head. The title you're referring to is part of a JSON Object.